# SilverStripe field-level Page editing permissions

Tags: silverstripe

I need to implement field-level permissions in a Page model, in a SilverStripe 3.2 website.

Let's imagine I have an `ArticlePage.php` model. It has the usual fields like `$MenuTitle` and `$Content`, and I've added other properties like `$Subtitle` and `$Author`.

I can protect the whole model by using `providePermissions()` and the associated `canEdit()` methods, but I need to protect individual fields / page properties.

What I need to do is:

- Admins should be able to edit all fields
- Users in another permissions group should only be able to edit and save `$Subtitle`

Is this possible in SilverStripe 3.2? Is there a *SilverStripe* way of doing it?

If not, is there a way I can Identify the user group of the current user and then perhaps conditionally show the `$field->addFieldToTab()` code? Is it possible to stop the user saving a field by posting the data maliciously, perhaps by adding the missing fields via inspector?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So here's my own answer. This post was helpful: https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/customising-the-cms/show/11693

You can conditionally show CMS fields and tabs using code like the post demonstrates:

```
public function getCMSFields()
    if(!Permission::check('PERMISSION_LABEL'){
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","MenuTitle");
        $fields->removeByName('BannerImages');
        // etc...
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Having defined the permission:

```
public function providePermissions()
{
    return array(
        'PERMISSION_LABEL' => 'Can edit some fields',
    );
}
```

My concern with this approach was that a user could still create a form field on the page using inspector or JS and submit values for fields they should not be able to see.

Having tested this it *appears* that field values are not saved if they are not listed on the page, but are sent with the POST data. Although I'd love to know if a SilverStripe expert could confirm that.